# Let $a,b,m,n\in\mathbb{N^*}$ with $\gcd(a,b)=1$. Is my proof correct that $(a^m,b^n)=1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

$\gcd(a,b)=1 \iff \exists k,l \in \mathbb{N^*}(ka+lb=1) $, by Bezout's identity.

Suppose $k=a^{m-1}\in \mathbb{N}$ and $l=b^{n-1}\in \mathbb{N}$.

Then $ka+lb=a^{m-1}a+b^{n-1}b=a^m+b^n=1$, as required.

I'm unsure about whether my proof is correct. Can someone check it out and let me know what you think? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no reason to suppose $k=a^{m-1}$ and $l=b^{n-1}$. Indeed  that is impossible, for the sum would not be $1$.

Comment: There is a kind of cute proof using the Bezout identity. Hint: take a large power of $ka+lb$. But there are more natural ways.

Comment: Yes, i have proved it through a more natural,as you say, way. Like only with words. It goes like: "Since $a,b$ are prime amongst themselves then they share no common factors. Clearly $a^m,b^n$ will also share no common factors, thus $(a^m,b^n)=1$". But i wanted a more rigorous proof. But i guessed it's pretty late, so i messed up.

Comment: We can do better. Suppose to the contrary that $\gcd(a^m,b^n)=d\gt 1$. Then some prime $p$ divides $d$. Thus $p\mid a^m$ and $p\mid b^n$. By Euclid's Lemma it follows that $p\mid a$ and $p\mid b$, contradicting the relative primality of $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: for all natural $a, m $, then if $p$ is a prime number, $p|a \iff p|a^m $.  That should be clear.  If $p|a \implies p|a*a^{m-1}=a^m $.  the nature of primes is that if $p|abc.... $ then $p $ divides one of the $a,b,c... $.  So $p|a^m=a*a*a.... \implies p|a $.

With that in mind this is simple.  $gcd (a,b)=1 $ means $a $ and $b$ have no common prime factors.  $a $ and $a^m $ have the exact same prime factors as do $b $ and $b^n$.  So $a$ and $b $ have no common prime factors iff $a^m $ and $b^n $ have no common prime factors. I.e. $gcd (a,b)=1 \iff gcd (a^m,b^n)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason, in your attempt, to suppose that $k$ may be a power of $a$ and that $l$ may also a power of $b.$ In fact if $a,b$ are each greater than $1, $ then one of $k,l$ must be negative in order that $a  k+ b l=1.$

1. If $1<n$ then $n$ is divisible by a prime. Proof: Let $m$ be the least of the divisors of $n$ that are greater than $1. $ Then $m$ is prime. For if $m=c d$  with $c>1<d$ then $c$ is a divisor of $n$ and is greater than $1$ but less than $m,$ contrary to the def'n of $ m.$

   2. If $p$ is prime and $s\in N$ and $p|x^s$ then $p|x.$ Proof: If not then $\gcd(p,x)=1$ (because $p$ is prime.)  So there are integers $A, B$ with $A p+B x=1,$ and we can either use the Binomial Theorem or induction on $s$ to show that $(1- A p )^s=1+k p$ for some integer $k.$

   But $(1-A p)^s=(B x)^s= B^s x^s$ is divisible by $p,$ so $(1-A p)^s$ is both a multiple of the prime $p, $ and $1$ more than a multiple of $p$, which is absurd.

   3. In the non-trivial case where $a>1$ and $b>1,$  and  where $m,n$ are positive:  If $d=\gcd(a^m,b^n)>1$ then $d$ is divisible by a prime $p$ (by 1.) But by 2., $\;p$ will divide both $a$ and $b,$ which implies $\gcd (a,b)\geq p>1.$